# How do I wrap methods in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wrapper

I have a lot of functions looking like this

```
  doSomething = async (...) => {
    try {
      this.setState({loading: true});

      ...
      var result = await Backend.post(...);
      ...

      this.setState({loading: false});
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState({error: err});
    }
  }
```

Basically I have 2 variables loading & error that I have to manage for a lot of functions and the code is basically the same for all of them. Since there are no decorators in javascript and I do not wish to install any experimental lib for that how could I wrap this function to remove the duplicated setStates from above ?

Comment: Why not just extract it to a method, so you do e.g. `doSomething = this.manageLoading(async () => { var result = await Backend.post(...); ... })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current way, I pass the function as parameter.

We have many API, fetch data form backend, we have to handle error and do something with data.

Only data of service are different, the handling error is the same.

```
private processServiceResponse(resp: any, doSthWithData: (data: any) => void) {
    let { errors } = resp;
    if (this.hasError(errors)) {
      this.handleServiceErr(errors);
      return;
    }
    let data = resp;
    if (resp && resp.data) {
      data = resp.data;
    }
    doSthWithData(data);
  }
```

And here is how i pass function as parameter.

```
let rest1 = service1.getData();
processServiceResponse(rest1,(data)=>{
//only need to focus with processing data.
})
```

PS: It's typescript coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Higher Order Function (a function that takes as argument another function) to make the common loading and error functionality reusable. It is **very** similar to a decorator pattern. For example:

```js
const doSomething = withLoadingAndErrorHandling(Backend.post, this.setState);


function withLoadingAndErrorHandling(fn, setState) {
    return async function(...args) {
       try {
          setState({loading: true});
          var result = await fn(args); 
          setState({loading: false});
          return result;
        } catch(err) {
          setState({error: err});
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using function conponents, you can define a custom hook to avoid repeat code

//useFetch.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      setLoading('loading...')
      setData(null);
      setError(null);
      const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
      axios.get(url, { cancelToken: source.token })
      .then(res => {
          setLoading(false);
          //checking for multiple responses for more flexibility 
          //with the url we send in.
          res.data.content && setData(res.data.content);
          res.content && setData(res.content);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          setLoading(false)
          setError('An error occurred. Awkward..')
  })
      return () => {
          source.cancel();
      }
  }, [url])

   return { data, loading, error }

export default useFetch;
```

usage:

```
import useFetch from './useFetch';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const { data: quote, loading, error } = 
useFetch('https://api.quotable.io/random')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { loading && <p>{loading}</p> }
      { quote && <p>"{quote}"</p> }
      { error && <p>{error}</p> }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```